# Remote connection of a Mac to a Linux server

Tags: linux, mac, lan, remote-access

Firstly, forgive my ignorance, but I am not into this kind of stuff...

There is a system of local computers (Linux) connected through LAN in an office. To each of these computers a hostname has been assigned. Is there a way to connect a Mac - which is in my home -  remotely to this LAN system using a new hostname?

For example, assume that there are 10 Linux computers (10 different hostnames) connected into the same local network. Is it possible to connect the Mac to the LAN system, so we can have 11 interconnected computers with 11 different hostnames?

Comment: Why don't you just use ssh, connecting to the Linux machine with its ip?

Comment: @Chong Could you just please explain?

Comment: Hi, can you be more clear about _"without engaging any of the existent usernames"_? What do you mean? Do you want to connect to that Linux machine using a different username? (If it exists, you have the password, sshd is up on that machine,there is no firewall on incoming connections, and you know the IP... )

Comment: If your computers are in a same local networks, you can directly connect to the computer with their local IP address, you can find it by `ifconfig` in your target computer. Then from your Mac, open terminal, `ssh [linux_user_name]@[ip of Linux ]` and it's good to go. I should mention that your Linux should have already installed `openssh` and is initiated, allowing remote login.

Comment: I'm afraid you are confusing the __username__, name of a user on a system,  with the __hostname__, name of a computer on a network. If so and you want to connect your computer in the net, it depends if the network is set to allow any computer to connect or if it waits for a specific couple ethernet port /MACADDRESS (it is not the address of a machintosh ;) ) Ask to the administrator or try directly! :)

Comment: @Hastur Is there an easy way to check that?

Comment: Connect the computer and see if you can go on internet, or if you can reach the other computers: if you know their local ip, maybe write in a shell of the Linux computer  `ifconfig` or `/sbin/ifconfig`,  you can ping it with : `ping  thelocalIPyouReadBefore`. If ping answer you are connected. (you can also write `ifconfig` on your mac after that it is connected).

Comment: It's totally unclear what you're trying to do. What do you mean by "connect a Mac remotely to this LAN system"? If they're both on the Internet, they're already connected. If you want them more connected, it would help an awful lot to know what you want to happen.

Answer (score 1):

It depends from the LAN:

1. Some LAN are set to allow any computer to connect with, maybe using DHCP <sup>[[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol)]</sup> and freeing the user to set DNS, Gateway and netmask.
2. Some others allow you to connect but you have to set manually your **IP**, the **DNS** <sup>[[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)]</sup>, the Gateway, **GW** <sup>[[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateway_%28telecommunications%29)]</sup> and the **netmask** <sup>[[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork)]</sup>.  Of course the Ip for a new machine have to be different from each of the other one used and in the range of the allowed connections. (E.g. If I have 10 computer with IP `192.168.1.100`...`192.168.1.110` I have to chose e.g. `192.168.1.119` to avoid conflicts).
3. Some other LAN instead aspect that only a specific computer can be connected to that specific port. When there are more ports than connected computer those are usually closed or however inhibited.
   The identification of the computer is usually made through its Mac Address <sup>[[5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address)]</sup>, less frequently through the operating system or with more severe level of security.

Under a Linux shell with the command `/sbin/ifconfig`, or simply `ifconfig` if sbin is in your PATH, you can read those parameters.

To know if a LAN allow other computer to be connected with you can

- ask to the administrators or other users
- if you have the right to do it you can connect your computer and check if it is able to communicate with the other ones (for example doing `ping 192.168.1.102` to connect the computer with the IP 192.168.1.102), and to go outside the LAN (if the LAN is open to a bigger net).

---

If you want to connect to one of this computer from your MAC you can do, for example, via `ssh username_on_linux_machine@IP_OF_LINUX_MACHINE` when you know the IP of the machine, you are on the same LAN, there is sshd (a deamon that accepts ssh connection) up on the receiving machine (the Linux one).

From outside this network can be a little more complicated and lan dependent; usually you connect to the gateway and from here you connect to the specific computer. Else you can join to the VPN if there is one, and from that moment is like if you were connected with a cable locally...

Comment: Thank you for the answer (upvoted).. I'll try to apply it.